# Problems with some constraints, gap between outlets increases as the screen increases

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I am going crazy over this. I cant seem to be able to fix the gap that occurs between the text and the images as shown in this picture below:

[image]

As you see the gap increases as the screen size increases and i dont know what constraint to add/remove or if its even that what is causing me this problem. I have uploaded the project and you can download to see the exact constraints or whatever helps you.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uvipjw0aq078cmu/StackO.zip?dl=0

Comment: and what behavior you want achieve?

Comment: So it looks like it does in 5.5-inch but with just little less gap. @ShadowOf

Comment: What gap are you talking about? And you want to fix it how?

Comment: If you take a look at the gap that is between the images(the house, camera etc..) and the text on the top. As you can see the gap increases ALOT when the screen is bigger(example is clearly seen on the ipad screen). That is the gap i am talking about. So i would like the result to be like in the 5.5 inch screen with a little less whitespace gap that it is currently showing. 

I would not be here if i knew how to fix it @Code

Comment: The 4-inch screen is a perfect exaple of how it should look. Everything is compact and close to each other. Allthough a little space between the text and the images would not hurt on the 4-inc screen @Code

Comment: I can not download your project, due to some dropbox lag probably. you need to set up resizing rule for your image at first. for example, add constraints that keep ratio, but align width to superview. also you may want to increase font size of your text; you should do it in code

Comment: My layout skills is as far as this goes. I have no idea how to implement the things you said. I was hoping that somebody could fix and post the solutions with a step by step tutorial on how and why they did stuff so i can learn from it. I know its much to ask @ShadowOf

Comment: Would you possible know which one ? @EICaptainv2.0

Comment: @TimoCengiz Remove the Bottom Constraint of the last component that is a blank image, and add a Vertical Constraint between the Label on the Top and Icons, its better to combine things in containers.

Comment: Which one is the "last component" ? Are you talking about the image above the " Broadcast Studio " label?  @iphonic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is how you want this screen to to look like:

[image: Result screenshot]

If yes, here is what you have to do: Add height constraint to your *Text View* and change relation of *Bottom Space to: Progress Bar* constraint of the *Masjid* label from *Equal* to *Greater Than or Equal*.

Of course you can manipulate the new height constraint to match your expectations.

[image: Height constraint screenshot]
[image: Relation change screenshot]

**[EDIT]**

If you want to make everything more centered, without stretching anything, you'll have to do few things. Change back the relation of *Masjid* constraint to *Equal*. Change relation of  *Text View.Top* to *Superview.Top* constraint to *Greater Than or Equal*. Add height constraint to *Web View*. Change relation of *Web View.Bottom* to *Superview.Bottom* constraint to *Greater Than or Equal*. Add *Vertical in Container* constraint to *Percentage Label*. This will left you with the *Tour The Construction Site* label floating around, but I don't know where it should be placed.

This is pretty complex screen, and you want it to look good in both, iPads and iPhones. You might want to check how to use the Size Classes. This would be a big help here.

Comment: Amazing work thank you, Just tried it out. Just by that i learned something new. Is there anyway to make everything more centered? Meaning the top part and the bottom part meet in the middle?

Comment: @TimoCengiz than you need to add all your views in some other view and give constraints to that .... which you actually done ... so you just need to use center x constraint to that view

Comment: So the white view should be inside another view? View inside a View? This is inception... @EICaptainv2.0

Comment: I assume that _top part_ includes: text view, icons and labels under icons. And _bottom part_ includes: web view, donate view, progress bar and percent labels above progress bar. Is my assumption correct? And second question, do you want the _bottom part_ to be stretched or just moved upwards?

Comment: @TimoCengiz your view hierarchy I check is well and good ... you just need to use center vertical constraint I think with scrollview

Comment: @tahavath indeed you are correct. Just moved upwards would be fine. Also a side question. How are you so good at this? is there any tutorials or something else you have done to understand how all this works. i really want to get better at this as it is my biggest weakness.

Comment: There are a lot of auto layout tutorials you can find in the internet (check the [www.raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com)). Beside this you just have to practice and try to solve problems on your own. I think this is the best way how you can learn this stuff.

Comment: I had to edit my answer, because describing how to do center everything didn't fit in the comments